# Custom domain with managed security getting expired certificate on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I am encountering a problem here with my Google App Engine project.
In fact, I hosted a GAE project with a custom domain and I chose to let Google manage the certificates but today I realized that my project's certificate expired more than a week ago and is still not renewed, Was I suppose to take another step to enable the certificate renewal?

**Custom domain Setting page**
[My custom domain mapping page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEbO1.png)

As you can see certificates generation and renewals should be managed by the Google Cloud Platform... That's what I thought

**Certificates page**
[Certificates expired since march 11th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5j7W.png)

I would really like to know how to fix this.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: My guess is that the domain ownership settings have changed. Read this link and verify your domains: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/verify-domain-name

Comment: That is not the case here as I still have full control on updating or deleting any related mapping... Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Second screenshot. Click on one of the expired certificates on `managed_certiicate`. Add a screenshot to show the custom domain mapped to the certificate. You may have orphaned certificates that are not being used, therefore they will not be renewed.

Comment: You are showing three custom domains but only two managed SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to the [Domain Troubleshooting page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#troubleshooting_managed_ssl_certificates).

I suggest contacting [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support#console-support-center) if you do not find the solution right away.